# Search all the occurrences of a string in the entire project in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, search, intellij-idea

I've just started using Android Studio (IntelliJ), and I now look for the feature to find the occurrence of a string in any of the files in my project. For example: I want to find all the files that contain the string "`.getUuid()`"

The search at the top right doesn't give me the correct results, and I don't think I can find this feature under Edit > Find.

Could anybody point me at the right direction?

Comment: I don't know if I understand your question, but if you want to find something in your file , push `Ctrl+R`.

Comment: @user2675569 - I don't want to find something in the file that I have open, I want to find it in all the files that are in the project. Any idea how I could do that?

Comment: to searc all in window is ctrl + h .. in mac is command + shift + f ..

Comment: if you want to export results to text file please see my answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/61691027/3904109

Answer (score 868, accepted):

**TLDR:** ⌃⇧F on MacOS will open "Find in path" dialog.

First of all, this IDEA has a nice "`Find Usages`" command. It can be found in the context menu, when the cursor is on some field, method, etc.

It's context-aware, and as far as I know, is the best way to find class, method or field usage.

Alternatively, you can use the

> Edit > Find > Find in path…

**dialog**, which allows you to search the whole workspace.

Also in IDEA 13 there is an awesome "`Search Everywhere`" option, by default called by double Shift. It allows you to search in project, files, classes, settings, and so on.

Also you can search from Project Structure dialog with "`Find in Path…`". Just call it by right mouse button on concrete directory and the search will be scoped, only inside that directory and it's sub-directory.

Enjoy!

Comment: Command-Shift-F on Mac to find in path, I am guessing Ctrl-Shift-F for Windows?

Comment: And Ctrl-Shift-R for replace.

Comment: Ctrl+Shift+F to find in path on MAC

Comment: @stevo.mit nope, see the first comment with 17+

Comment: @Erik B Yes I saw it, but it didn't work for me. I did not customize shortcuts in my Android Studio and the shortcut is (at least on my Mac) Ctrl+Shift+F

Comment: That's the exact reason, why I haven't included any shortcuts in answer. You can always check everything in keymap and change it.

Comment: Maybe a "windows" keyboard and the command is mapped to ctrl?

Comment: Ctrl+Shift+F for Linux

Comment: TIP: make sure File Name Filter is according to your needs. I had it default to build.gradle and boom never nothing appropriate was found in the search..phew.. I need more tome to get used to Android Studio.

Comment: If you are like me and use this all the time, you might want to set a simpler shortcut as well by going to Preferences --> Keymap --> Main Menu --> Edit --> Find --> Find in path...

Comment: Studio also great features to filter out comments for example https://postimg.cc/image/axl41486j/

Comment: Since Android Studio 4.0 the combination has changed -> the default combination is now  on MAC OS X Catalina -> Control (^) + Shift + F. To get back the classic combination with command instead of control as start you need to edit the keyboard shortcuts in android studio's preferences.

Comment: The `search everywhere` option finds nothing.

Comment: Does anyone know why this command is so fast? how can it find a character array in gigabyte project within milliseconds? @Kushal

Comment: @Maddocks Indexing. I'm not sure what and how exactly do they index, but if you are really curious, I'd recommend looking at Community Edition's source code for hints. [Here for example I can see a code doing text search using trigram indices](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/master/platform/indexing-impl/src/com/intellij/find/ngrams/TrigramTextSearchService.java)

Answer (score 182):

In Android Studio on a Windows, macOS or Linux based machine use shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> to search any string in whole project. It's easy to remember considering <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> is used to search in the current file. So just press the <kbd>Shift</kbd> as well.

Comment: Does not work if you set Eclipse key bindings. Ctrl + Shift + F is format.

Comment: There are 13 options how to set key binding. Switch back to "Default" and it will work. Otherwise it is up to you to learn your setting. (FYI: it is Ctrl+H for "Eclipse" key binding)

Comment: Can we find and replace all in a project too?

Comment: If you want to export the results into a text file then please see my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/61691027/3904109

Answer (score 69):

Press <kbd>Shift</kbd> twice and a Search Everywhere dialog will appear.

Comment: Strangely enough, it doesn't find every occurrence, but `Ctrl` + `shift` + `F` does.

Comment: @Whitebird Yeah, I'm not sure why. I tend to use Ctrl + Shift + F a lot more, even though the results aren't as pretty.

Comment: Double `shift` can not search Chinese characters,but `Ctrl`+`shift`+`f` does

Comment: `Double Shift` search for non project things as well like settings. So as it does long works its time consuming. Try `Ctrl + Shift + F` if you want only things in project, its much faster than `Double Shift`

Answer (score 16):

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> combination for Windows and Linux to search everywhere, it shows preview also.

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> combination for Windows and Linux to search in current file.

Use <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> (Double Tap Shift) combination for Windows and Linux to search Project File of Project.

Answer (score 16):

You can open the *Find in Path* dialog by pressing:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>

Answer (score 11):

Android Studio Version 4.0.1 on **Mac** combination is for me:

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>

Answer (score 10):

Android Studio 3.3 seems to have changed the shortcut to search for all references (find in path) **on macOS**.

In order to do that you should use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> now (instead of <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> as wrote on the previous answers):

**UPDATE**

To replace in path just use  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>.

[image]

Comment: Is there an option to replace all occurrences of a particular string?

Comment: @calistus I've updated the answer. Take a look to see how to replace in path.

Answer (score 8):

And for all of us who use Eclipse keymaps the shortcut is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>. Expect limited options compared to eclipse or you will be disappointed.

Comment: Yeah, it really depends on what keymap you are using. Mine was Eclipse's.

Answer (score 7):

In Android Studio on a Windows or Linux based machine use shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> to search and replace any string in the whole project.

Answer (score 6):

What you want to reach is that, I believe:

- <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> for classes.
- <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> for files.
- **<kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>**  for symbols. "wonderful shortcut!"

Besides <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>f</kbd> for find in path && double shift to search anywhere.
Play with those and you will know what satisfy your need.

Answer (score 3):

use `ctrl` + `shift` + `f` on windows

Answer (score 2):

Press **<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>** 2   times and you can search Every-where , both Class and Method() in the project.

**<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd>** for finding only Class name.

**<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>** for Recent Files.

Answer (score 1):

In Android 3.6 on a Mac if you want to export the results to a text file then do the following

**Command+Shift+F** then enter the text you want to search

Then on **Bottom Right** click on **"Open In Find Window"**

Then **Right Click** On **Found Occurrences**

Then **Export To Text File**

Once in text file you can find and replace to remove, sort lines etc... please see screenshots for assistance.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> combination in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

On a mac use <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>cmmd</kbd> + <kbd>f</kbd>

To get rid of the screen press <kbd>esc</kbd>

I use `IntelliJ IDEA`
version: `2019.2.3 (Community Edition)`
Build #`IC-192.6817.14, built on September 24, 2019`
Runtime version: `11.0.4+10-b304.69 x86_64`