# How to search all files for a string in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

In Android Studio (*IntelliJ*) how do you execute a 'File Search' for a string within a Scope of files? Can *Search Everywhere* do this, I only see how to use it to search 'code', not 'files'

**Example:** Search for the string "Dummy Button" in the 'Workspace Scope'.

**Expected Response:** *res/values/string.xml:line4*

Answer (score 73, accepted):

You can do it in two ways,

Goto **`Menu -> Edit -> Find -> Find in Path`**

[image]

Or use the shortcut,

**`ctrl+shift+f`**

Comment: I am well aware of Find in Path, but I struggle when trying to find something, a class name for example, within the dependencies of my project (generally things I see in "External Libraries" portion of the file list). Any tips for making that work? An example would be search for "FirebaseAuthException" in a project which includes firebase-auth-interop, which contains a class named FirebaseAuthException.

Comment: If you want to export the results into a text file please see here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/61691027/3904109

Comment: Is there a way to `add search path` to existing search path?

Answer (score 18):

In Android Studio,

1. On a Windows or Linux based machine use shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> to search any string in whole project. It's easy to remember considering <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> is used to search in the current file. So just press the <kbd>Shift</kbd> as well.
2. On OSX use the <kbd>Command</kbd> key instead of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>.
3. Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> combination for Windows and Linux to search in current file.
4. Use <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> (Double Tap <kbd>Shift</kbd>) combination for Windows and Linux to search Project File of Project.
5. <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> on Mac to find in path

Answer (score 11):

In Android Studio 4.1 update, the combination for Mac users changed, now you should use `Control` + `Shift` + `f`.

Comment: In Android 4.1.3 the combination for Mac users is slightly different: `Control` + `Shift` + `f`.

Comment: The same is true for replacements, which for one file is `Cmd`+`R` but for "in files" it's `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`R`. Completely unintuitive, luckily one can use BetterTouchTool or similar tools to add a custom keyboard shortcut to translate the `Cmd` variant into the other.

Answer (score 10):

Try this. Enter your string name in dialogue box after pressing `ctrl+shift+f`

Comment: if you had any idea how happy the speed and clarity have now made my Saturday AM. THANK YOU!!!! :)

Answer (score 8):

Menu Bar->Edit->Find->Find in Path...

Answer (score 7):

**Press Two times Shift button** and write in search box it will search in whole Android studio.

Comment: please accept my answer so also help to other developer

Comment: please remove this option, this is for 'Search Everywhere', which does not allow you to 'search files'! Or alternatively please show how to achieve the 'Expected Response' above. I just tried your methodology and came up empty

Answer (score 5):

In my case, I accidentally checked the box of "File mask". So all xml files are not searchable in Find in Path. Maybe this can help you.
[image]

Comment: An interesting setting, haven’t use this before. Great reference though, thank you for sharing