# What is the shortcut to search for a text inside all project files in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, keyboard-shortcuts, text-search

I need to find a text occurrence inside all files and classes in Android Studio. I am unable to achieve it with the double <kbd>Shift</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>. Is there any shortcut key for that?

Answer (score 1):

Try Out this

```
Ctrl + Shift + F to search any string in whole project
```

[How to search all files for a string in Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32540620/how-to-search-all-files-for-a-string-in-android-studio)

Comment: Not working, I want to search the content of all activities and fragments, like if I want to search for word "user" inside all activities

Comment: yes this works perfectly fine.. and follow link I have provided it has some more ways.

Comment: I have already gone through the link, it is not serving my purpose.

Comment: are you using windows?

Comment: same, and its working perfectly fine for me and everyone else out here.