# How to find usages of Strings.xml in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, localization

You can get "Show usages of field xyz" with the help of cursor & command (in Mac) in Java,How to find where specific xml tag has been used?
For example how to find usage of ***Hello*** key:
`<string name="Hello">Hello world</string>`

Comment: Alt+F7 (find usage) on resource name or Ctrl+Shift+F (search entire project) for value.

Comment: Thanks a lot @AndriyOmelchenko, You saved a lot of my time :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20252716/4585226 Take a look at this answer

Answer (score 15):

Right-click on the resource name in the strings.xml (in your case, on `Hello`) or on the id in the code and select **Find usages**. This will give you the usages of this res.

OSX     Command-Option-F7
Windows Alt + F7

Comment: I don't like this process. From java code if I press CTRL+Click on a R,string.hello file then it shows that where the "hello" text appears. but from strings.xml folder I can't do that.. Have there any solution on that?

Comment: On windows its Alt+F7