# Duplicate instance of GradientColor_fontVariationSettings in R.java android studio

Tags: java, android

I've been coding around in android studio for a decent bit now. Recently an issue popped up where the project would be unable to compile and I traced down the error to a duplicate variable

```
public static final int GradientColor_fontVariationSettings = 13;
public static final int GradientColor_fontVariationSettings = 14;
```

in the file R.java. I removed this but since it is auto-generated, it simply adds it again and fails to compile once more. The error I am getting is variable GradientColor_fontVariationSettings is already defined in class styleable.

EDIT: I found the file and deleted the reference, but the issue is still occuring. Any ideas anybody

Comment: Please add the path of R.java to the question. It's for your package or android one? And class  name which contains GradientColor_fontVariationSettings, for example `attr` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GradientColor_fontVariationSettings means [fontVariationSettings](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#fontVariationSettings) attribute of GradientColor class. So, check res/attr, shapes in res/drawable folder which uses gradient and other gradient related resources. If nothing seems suspicious, check imported libraries.

If you want to find "GradientColor" or "fontVariationSettings" occurence in a / entire project, Android Studio has a menu "Find in path".

Refs.

[Drawable resources - Shape drawable](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource#Shape)

[GradientDrawable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/GradientDrawable)

[Search all the occurrences of a string in the entire project in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20252180/search-all-the-occurrences-of-a-string-in-the-entire-project-in-android-studio)

Updated:

Edit > Find > Find Usage may help to search usages.

Comment: I will try this out

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but you may find it under **res** folder

Comment: I found it, but even after editing the problem was not fixed after switching it back