# Android Studio Search (Ctrl + Shift + F) doesn't search all occurrences of a string

Tags: android, string, android-studio, search

Android Studio Search (Ctrl + Shift + F) doesn't search all occurrences of a string.

Why is this happening?
I tried setting scope to "In Project", "Module", "Directory" and even custom scope.

I already have gone through this post and other such posts.
[Search all the occurrences of a string in the entire project in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20252180/search-all-the-occurrences-of-a-string-in-the-entire-project-in-android-studio)

Comment: I have the same problem in Android Studio Hedgehog 2023.1.1 Patch 1: Edit / Find  / Find in files . I enter a search string that I know exists in files, untick File Mask, I select search in Directory, Regex disabled - result is Nothing found. I do the same search from another tool (Total commander), and it gives me hits in 5 different .java files, same casing, all real. Cache invalidation didn't help. If I open one of those files in Android Studio, CTRL-F for the same string finds all expected hits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try these steps below?

- Is the file containing "searched" text is in a directory `Marked as Excluded`?
- Is `File Mask` activated?
- Is `Regex` filter activated?
- Is `Search Filter Popup` searchs `Anywhere`?
- Is the project indexed. Try to invalidate caches.

Hope, it helps.

Comment: 1. No, 
2. No, 
3. No, 
4. Yes, 
5. Not Sure (How to Index the project?)

Comment: File > Invalidate Caches.

Comment: Thank you! :) [[ File > Invalidate Caches ]] did the trick ..